# Instagram Basic display Api (Not Able to get user Access token iOS Swift)

Tags: authentication, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I want users of my iOS app to login via instagram.
As Instagram discontinued previous method, I am using Instagram Basic Display Api.
Is that okay to use this Api for authentication??
Secondly I have created an App on facebook developer site and setup instagram app and got instagram App ID.
Now How can I get user access token using this App ID??

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={instagram-app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope={scope}
  &response_type=code
  &state={state}        //Optional
```

I am hitting this url with App ID and redirect uri in postman and in browser.It is not working and showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load with webVieW

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=\(clientId)&redirect_uri=\(redirectUri)&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```